# Cash limit counting in traveling to US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, money, paperwork

The [CBP document](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195) states that

> There is no limit on the amount of money that can be taken out of or brought into the United States. However, if a person or persons traveling together and filing a joint declaration (CBP Form 6059-B) have $10,000 or more in currency or negotiable monetary instruments, they must fill out a "Report of International Transportation of Currency and Monetary Instruments" [FinCEN 105](http://www.fincen.gov/forms/files/fin105_cmir.pdf) (former CF 4790)."

What does *persons traveling together and filing a joint declaration (CBP Form 6059-B)* mean?

Is *filing a joint declaration of 6059-B* the way of determining *persons travelling together*? Or are there other ways to determine, and *filing joint 6059-B* is just one of them?

I don't know what this would affect if I and my mom just happen to be on same flight but she goes to tour visit but I am going home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an explanation of the specifics of who is eligible to file a single form 6059-B.  Basically you need to meet [3 conditions](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/441/~/travelers-eligible-to-file-a-joint-or-family-declaration-on-a-cbp-form-6059b) for eligibily according to CBP.

> 1. Are related by blood, marriage, or adoption;
> 2. Lived together in one household at their last permanent residence; and
> 3. Intend to live together in one household after their arrival in the United States.

So if you don't live together and not intend to live together you should file separate forms.

Comment: Ok, I see. If she visit somewhere else and I am back to home with a different address which in fact does not live together, this is ok to file separately. I can't rule out the possibility she will stay with us maybe for a few days at the end of tour, but I guess what you saying if the intent here is that she isn't planning to just live with us, then its ok to file separately.

Comment: The page [linked by the OP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195) still sounds strange -- whereas you're talking about _eligibility_ to file a joint form, the situation here seems to be that filing a joint form _takes away_ rights (namely the entire group can now bring less cash across the border than if they filed separately), so part of the question is whether persons traveling together who are _eligible_ to file jointly are also _required_ to file jointly and therefore are subject to the tighter currency restrictions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If they are eligible to file a single form they should. Otherwise you can't truthfully sign the customs declaration form.

Comment: @Karlson: What would be untrue? The form itself says "only ONE form per family is _required_", not "only ONE form per family is _allowed_". (Emphasis mine). Such a rule would mean that, for example, people who happen to be family according to the US definition (including, e.g. adult offspring who live with their parents but otherwise have their own economy) would be barred from traveling on the same flight unless they're all willing to disclose to each other how much cash they're bringing, whether they've recently been on a farm etc.

Comment: @HenningMakhom You will fail the number of family members traveling with you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm And all of this only apply if they are traveling together.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you and your mother do not reside together, since you write that she is on a visit while you are going home.

If this is in fact true, you should file separate forms.  The definition of family members has been expanded to "members of a family residing in the same household who are related by blood, marriage, domestic relationship, or adoption."  (Source: http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/CBP-declaration-form-6059B).

The meaning of "persons traveling together and filing a joint declaration (CBP Form 6059-B)" is fairly plain: to fall under that definition, you must be both traveling together and filing a joint form.  In fact, of course, you cannot file a joint form if you are not traveling together, so the reason for this clause is clearly to say that the limit applies to the entire family when family members file a joint form, but that it applies separately to people who travel together but file separate forms.