# Money limit in the airport

Tags: usa, airports, money, california, san-francisco

Is there a limit to the money I can carry with me (in my suitcase) at the San Francisco, California, United States of America airport?

If so, which is that limit? I will depart from SF.

Comment: Are you going to San Francisco, or flying from ?

Comment: @blackbird didn't know that this will make a difference, leave, edited!

Comment: Are you asking if there is a limit on cash you can take into or out of the United States, or a limit on cash that you can physically bring onto the grounds of San Francisco International Airport? The U.S. imposes no limits whatsoever on how much cash you can carry, but you must declare your cash to customs when entering the country if it exceeds $10,000 or its equivalent foreign value.

Comment: @choster I will depart from the airport of SF. I have never been to US before, so forgive my ignorance. What am I asking is if there is a limit to the money I can curry with me as I leave SF..

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36740/is-there-a-legal-limit-to-the-amount-of-cash-one-can-carry-on-domestic-us-flight?rq=1

Comment: How can you depart from SF if you have never been to the US?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cash limit counting in traveling to US](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47106/cash-limit-counting-in-traveling-to-us)

Comment: Oh @CMaster I thought that after writing that, I mean I have never been to US before, thus I have never left, so it will be my 1st time leaving US. Karlson I think the answer here is much better than the link you posted now..However, it seems that I will not carry any cash with me at all, the answers suggest that it will not be a piece of cake.

Comment: Some cash is certainly ok and quite common. It's when you're talking about large amounts of cash that it becomes an increasingly bad idea.

Comment: @Karlson Clearly not a duplicate of that question. That question is asking about circumstances under which two related people get to have separate allowances; this is asking about one person.

Comment: I can imagine a carry-on with 100 $100 dollar bills in it may prompt a TSA security screener to ask if it is okay to open your carry-on, and of course you always say yes.  And then your fellow travelers may get a good peek at your stack of cash!

Comment: I see @MarkStewart, I will not do it...!

Comment: @DavidRicherby http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66328/usa-travelling-with-more-than-usd-10-000?rq=1  If not one it's the other.

Comment: @Karlson No, it's neither. That's a question about whether the recipient of large sums of cash needs to declare it in the US. "Duplicate" means "the same question", not "another question about a related subject."

Comment: My boyfriend was traveling from California to Indiana with $10,000 in cash. He was "detained" until he could pay a $600 fine. He couldn't use any of the money he had because it had also been "detained" but he is supposed to get it back once he pays the $600.

Comment: @choster cash and equivalents with a total value of $10,000 or more must also be declared when leaving the US, not only when entering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no limit to the amount of cash you can carry in the United States. However, some caveats apply.

First, if you (where you is either a single person or a group of people traveling together) are carrying more than $10,000 USD in currency (including foreign currency) or negotiable monetary instruments in or out of the United States, you [must declare it](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195/kw/10000%20dollars/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ3MDE1NzI4OC9zaWQvb18xWGk0WG0%3D/suggested/1). Remember that this rule applies both entering and leaving the United States; even though you probably will not see a US Customs officer when leaving, the declaration is required and you must go to the Customs office. There are harsh penalties for failure to declare currency, so it's important to follow the procedures.

Second, [civil asset forfeiture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States) is, while not incredibly common, something that can happen. If the police believe that your cash, even if less than $10,000, could be associated with crime, often with little to no evidence, they can seize it and you'd have to go to court to try to get it back. Since most legal business doesn't involve carrying that much cash around, traveling with significant amounts of money could arouse suspicion. While there are a number of ongoing efforts to reform these laws and police procedures, it is a risk, and not carrying large amounts of cash is a way to address that risk. If you must travel with a significant amount of cash, the authorities may want to know where it comes from, so carrying documentation that demonstrates its lawful origin may be helpful.

Lastly, there's the risk of theft or loss. Americans don't typically carry large amounts of cash; we often use bank transfers, electronic payments, and even plain old fashioned paper checks. If possible, I'd recommend leaving the money in the bank and transferring it as needed.

Also remember that the country you are bringing the money to may have restrictions or declaration requirements, and that any country you are transiting through may also impose requirements. You'll need to comply with any relevant laws in the US, transit countries, and your destination.

Comment: I was thinking to take the money with me because when I will be back to my country, I will have to withdraw them and undergo the taxes of the bank here in USA. I had to withdraw money from my country from here and I payed many extra costs, so I am trying to think of a way of avoiding that! But yes, I don't use cash either!

Comment: US Banks do not charge significant fees for a withdrawal. Sometimes there is an account-closing fee, maybe $25. Withdrawal by check is $1 or $2 more. I *strongly* dis-recommend carrying cash of tens of thousands of dollars, for security reasons.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus you should have tagged me, I hadn't see your valuable comment! Yes there is a closing fee. However, what are you saying is that while I am going to be in my country, I will go to the bank and do what exactly instead of going to the ATM or the cashier to get the money in cash?

Comment: @gsamaras My first recommendation would be that you take in cash a reasonable amount for travel expenses (that might be on the order of $500) and have the bank _wire_ the remainder of the money to your bank account in Home Country. (If Home Country == Iran, I don't think this works.) For this, you would have a closing fee and also a wire fee of $25-30. If we are talking in the $10,000+ range, $50 to avoid theft and loss issues is worth it. Depending on the type of account, you could also leave a token $100 here in the USA. (continued)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus my country is Greece and the bank here is one of the biggest around..

Comment: @gsamaras For amounts in between $500 and $10,000, you should ask your Home Country bank what their policy is on an American bank check (also called a cashier's check), which you can get made out to yourself. The fee for a bank check is much lower than for a wire transfer, but a wire transfer is same-or-next-day credit, while a bank check may not be credited to you for weeks after you submit it at home.